# Git checkout just aborts

Tags: git, macos, debugging, abort, git-checkout

So, I've freshly cloned a repo. I want to switch to a branch and it unhelpfully just aborts:

```
git checkout II-13
...
...
html/icons/EJ4/AJ/ucp-ico
Aborting
```

This is on an up to date Mac. Ideas? Ideas on debugging?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem today after Ctrl-C-ing out of a 'git checkout' for git version 2.12.3.  I was able to fix it by deleting the branch I was trying to switch to and re-checking it out.

That is, for your case, the following worked for me:

```
git branch -d II-13
git checkout II-13
```